# how do you change img src with javascript depending on browser width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I would like to change the source of the image element with the id of "front". I have a basic script at the top, but it doesn't work. I was just attempting to come up with something but I'm very bad at JavaScript.

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="home.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var reswidth=screen.width;

if (reswidth<400){
  var x = document.getElementsById("front");
  x.src="../images/colbysmall.png"
}

</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="header">
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
  <li><a id="home" href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="../portfolio/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="../contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="x"></div>

</div>
</head>



<body>
<div class="website">


<div class="logo"></div>

<img src="../images/ColbyFaceblack.jpg" id="front" width="100%" >
<div class="content">
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="office"></div>


</div>



<div class="body2">

<img src="../images/simple_dashed_full.png" width="100%">

<div class="weboutline">
    <img src="../images/web_outline.png" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="body2img2">
    <img src="../images/portfolio.png" width="100%">
</div>

<div class="body2img3">
    <img src="../images/blog.png" width="100%">
</div>

</div>
<div class="body3">

<img src="../images/body.png" width="100%">
<img class="touch" src="../images/get_in_touch_beige.png" width="50%">




</div>

<footer>
<img src="../images/footer.png" width="100%">
    <div class="copyright"> copyright COLBY MOFFETT 2015 </div>
    <div class="facebook"></div>
    <div class="instagram"></div>
    <div class="twitter"></div>
</footer>






</body>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: You are executing your code in the `<head>` section BEFORE the DOM has been loaded so the DOM elements are not yet there.  If you have jQuery, you can use `$(document).ready()` to schedule the code to run when the DOM has been loaded.  You probably also want to run the code when the window resizes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, the following could be one of the solutions:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($( window ).width() < 400) { 
        $("img#front").attr("src","../images/colbysmall.png");
    } else {
        $("img#front").attr("src","../images/ColbyFaceblack.jpg");
    }
});
```

(PS. Untested code) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is right, but has to be executed on change of screen size:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    var reswidth=screen.width;
    if (reswidth<400){
      var x = document.getElementsById("front");
      x.src="../images/colbysmall.png"
    }
  });
});
```

Also make sure you execute it inside the `$(function () { });` to execute on the DOM loaded contents. So, to make sure it also executes when it gets loaded, you need to store it in a named function and execute it every time when the window is resized.

Your final code will be:

```
$(function () {
  var reszWindow = function () {
    var reswidth=screen.width;
    if (reswidth<400){
      var x = document.getElementsById("front");
      x.src="../images/colbysmall.png"
    }
  };
  reszWindow();
  $(window).resize(reszWindow);
});
```

Comment: This won't run the code the first time when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Perhaps storing it into a named function, calling this function on `resize` event and on DOM ready could do it... unless the resize function is automatically called onload.

Comment: I took part of this and combined it with another answer and it works really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

changing image according to screen resolution:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var scrWidth = $(window).width();
    if(scrWidth < 500){
        $('#myImage').attr('src', 'http://wallpaper-download.net/wallpapers/logo-wallpapers-google-chrome-background-wallpaper-33143.jpg');
    }
    if(scrWidth > 500){
        $('#myImage').attr('src', 'http://www.bhmpics.com/download/google_colorful_background-1920x1080.jpg');
    }
});
```

(random images from google)

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/59ehtLde/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript aside, you can do this with just HTML5.  Browser support [isn't great,](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) but isn't bad, either.

```html
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="../images/colbysmall.png">
   <img src="../images/ColbyFaceblack.jpg">
</picture>

<p>With placeholders:</p>

<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/400?text=colbyfaceblack">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=colbysmall">
</picture>
```