# Changing the background image if window is resized to 800px in width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write code that changes the `background-image` of the `body` if the window is resized. My code is below, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width(1000px)(function() {
        $(body).css("background-image":"url(images/background-mobile.svg)");
    }));
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: CSS media queries would be much better suited to this than using JavaScript

Comment: [A similar case can be found at:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702576/how-do-you-change-img-src-with-javascript-depending-on-browser-width/32702806#32702806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the `if` statement, the `width()` and `css()` functions and the `body` selector are incorrect. You also need to execute this code on the `resize` event of the window. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() < 1000) {
            $('body').css('background-image', "url('images/background-mobile.svg')");
        } else { 
            // default setting for desktop here...
            $('body').css('background-image', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

All that being said, you should really use CSS media queries for this:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('images/background-mobile.svg');
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me but media queries don't work well on resize. At the very least it's not reliable. I'd say jQuery or vanilla JS is the way to go here.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your code I'm afraid. Media queries are by far the better approach. They are hardware accelerated and as such perform much better than the equivalent JS. It's also better for Separation of Concerns, as having JS tied to the UI is far from ideal.

Comment: I'm always willing to reevaluate code but there's only so much of it in a media query...

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what you are looking for here - will it be at 800px and only 800px? Do you want it to change at 800px and up or 800 and below?

If you are handling this via CSS:

*(I assume because of your image 'background-mobile.svg' you are going to want to use the 800px or less example)*

**800px and up**

```
body {
  background-image:url('images/your-default-desktop-img.jpg');
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-image:url('images/background-mobile.svg');
  }
}
```

**800px or less**

```
body {
  background-image:url('images/your-default-desktop-img.jpg');
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-image:url('images/background-mobile.svg');
  }
}
```

As far as a jQuery/JavaScript solution goes, I would try something like this (based on your original code):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(window).width() < 800){
    $('body').css("background-image":"url(images/background-mobile.svg)");
  } else {
      $('body').css("background-image":"url(images/background-desktop.svg)");
  }
});
```

Also, I just noticed, the reason your original function isn't working is *most likely* due to the fact that you forgot to enclose your "body" selector in single quotes for jQuery - it's going to treat your $(body) as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> When calling .width("value"), the value can be either a string (number and unit) or a number.

You're specifying a number and a unit in your example, therefore, you'll need to pass a string.

```
.width(1000px) //incorrect
.width("1000px") //correct
```

Apart from this, your code won't check for the window's size, but instead will set it to the specified value which is not what you want to achieve in this case.

You should do something like this instead:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1000){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use CSS for this. The @media rule was made specifically for this purpose. W3Schools has a page that pretty much covers exactly what you're looking to do using CSS: [CSS Media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

in your css

```
.changeBackgroundClass
{
    background-image:url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg');
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px)
{
    .changeBackgroundClass
    {
        background-image:url('http://wikipics.net/photos/20150125142221651988185.jpg');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
        if (thisWidth < 1000) {
            $('body').css('background-image', "url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQpRqXxjfL2LiYNRcl1TDaEkI8EPqxNvw5-O4Z6WhgF6sTuWbz-')");
        } else { 
            // default setting for desktop here...
            $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q82L5myj/